# Update server with unsynched file from VS

Tags: c++, docker, visual-studio-2019, remote-debugging

I code in C++ with VS19. I debug on a remote machine (specifically a docker container), which means that my IDE copies the changed files whenever I hit the debug button and build the program in the target.

My remote machine isn't stable and sometimes it restarts and reverts to the initial state of my image.

When it does, I usually have files on the IDE that have been already copied to the remote machine before. When I start debugging, my IDE thinks there is nothing to update the server, and executes the program remotely. The thing is that the files on the remote are outdated and then my debug is showing wrong lines and an outdated version is executed.

The only solution I have found so far it to do a minor change in all the files that I remember that I have changed, which in turn tells the IDE to update those files on the remote.

This is really hard and sometimes files are missed.
I have found nothing about it online, will be glad to hear if someone tackled this problem.

Comment: How many files are there (total?) Maybe some kind of script that touches them all (to change the last modification date) would work for you.

Comment: @PaulSanders there are a few hundreds (it is a legacy project). A script is an option, but I try to understand if there is a cleaner option :)

Comment: Does this problem occur on other computers? Or is this problem caused by the remote machine? For multi-file processing, scripts are indeed a good choice.